# how can i change redis to mysql in controller.php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, redis, mariadb

how can i change it to non use redis. in .env i dont have redis as DB_CONNECTION. idk how i can delate this redis, cuz without ingerence i cant start my website... big thx to help and any answer.

here is my controller.php where is error in 31-33

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use LRedis;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public $user;
    public $redis;
    public $title;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTitle('Title not stated');
        if(Auth::check())
        {
            $this->user = Auth::user();
            view()->share('u', $this->user);
        }
        $this->redis = LRedis::connection();
        view()->share('steam_status', $this->getSteamStatus());
    }

    public function  __destruct()
    {
        $this->redis->disconnect();
    }

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        view()->share('title', $this->title);
    }

    public function getSteamStatus()
    {
        $inventoryStatus = $this->redis->get('steam.inventory.status');
        $communityStatus = $this->redis->get('steam.community.status');

        if($inventoryStatus == 'normal' && $communityStatus == 'normal') return 'good';
        if($inventoryStatus == 'normal' && $communityStatus == 'delayed') return 'normal';
        if($inventoryStatus == 'critical' || $communityStatus == 'critical') return 'bad';
        return 'good';
    }

}
```

this is my .env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=l2ggh1imVxJ7Oj6BotPUWinAIDgJfBYw
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=csgo
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=4563

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

pplssss help me !

Comment: you are using the mysql db right?

Comment: exactly.. and my database in mysql for this website is called "csgo"

Comment: what is the table you are accessing

Comment: when i start the server i got error with controller.php which i add in thread.

Comment: You should remove the lines related to redis connection and disconnection, and read the inventory and community status from mysql using two Eloquent models.

Comment: this is my website ip : http://46.41.137.45:4563/ i try remove redis connection. btw how read status using two eloquent models ??

Answer (score 0):

You can access you database tables like this
First you need add this code in the top of your file

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Then

```
$steamDetail= DB::table('steam')->get();//This will return all the data from steam table
$steamStatusArray=DB::table('steam')->pluck('status');//This will return only the status column from steam table
```

[Reference- Laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries)

Note: you have to remove all the code related to `LRedis`
If you don't know where to start give a try on this **[tutorial](https://selftaughtcoders.com/from-idea-to-launch/lesson-17/laravel-5-mvc-application-in-10-minutes/)**. It might give you the idea.

Comment: i do it all what you say but again error.... could you change all my controlers.php to mysql ?? i do something wrong i think ;/

Comment: pls help me.. i remove all LRedis but still doesnt work.

Comment: @danieldaniellllllo The error occurs because you can't access the data directly, It will return as the array, you need to loop and get the data. Did you gone through the docs?  Remove the code related to LRedis also..... Show what error you got

Comment: @danieldaniellllllo remove this line `use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;`

Comment: i answered you in answer topic. not comment.

Comment: wait, you have to create a different controller, don't alter the exisitng one... best thing is go through the laravel docs and start coding